# How to dynamically add external javascript libs to created/updated elements in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a simple React app in codepen: https://codepen.io/ch3rn0v/pen/owBKqm?editors=1011.

**For example, here is the JS part:**

```
var EmailInput = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div class="input-field">
                <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" />
                <label for="email" data-error="Please enter a valid email" data-success="That's a valid email">Email</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<EmailInput />, document.getElementById('test'));
```

When I add material ui js lib and corresponding css styles, they correctly apply to the static html elements.
But when I create some html elements dynamically, the material ui js lib does not apply to those dynamically added elements.
How do I make the lib look for the newly created elements manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using JSX syntax you must use `className` instead of `class` and `htmlFor` instead of `for` as thouse are reserved keywords in javascript (more info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)).

Like this:

```
var EmailInput = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="input-field">
                <input id="email" type="email" className="validate" />
                <label htmlFor="email" data-error="Please enter a valid email" data-success="That's a valid email">Email</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<EmailInput />, document.getElementById('test'));
```